# jQuery to set css value of one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help with setting "padding left" of `<div id="menu">` to equal the width of `<ol>`

Here's an example code for reference

```
<ol style="width:80%">some code</ol>

<div id="menu">some text</div>
```

I'm trying to do it with jQuery, I don't know it well so this is my attempt

```
$("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": "$('ol').width()"});
```

It works only if I enter a value myself like 400px in here `$("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": "400px"});`

But this is for a responsive design and I want it to automaticaly get the value of `<ol>` element and in pixes

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it works. One thing though, when I re-size the browser it doesn't change the value to the new width. Only if I refresh. How do I make it update automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"` from `"$('ol').width()"` otherwise it will not work

```
$("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": $('ol').width()});
```

If you want to change the padding while changing the size then put it inside window **[`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** event

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": $('ol').width()});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So close!

```
$("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": $('ol').width()});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": $('ol').width()});
```

Answer (score 1):

## [From jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

you can check the method `.css( propertyName, value )` and figure it out.

By the way, when you refresh your window size. code like this:

```
$(window).resize(function (){
   $("#menu").css({"paddingLeft": $('ol').width()});
})
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you for that last bit of help.